# Get string from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a number of forms in my application.

A few of them display a pop up form which is similar to a browse file dialog. How can I return the folder path selected by the user back to the previous form?

```
BrowseTree bTree = new BrowseTree(connection);
bTree.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
DialogResult dialogResult = bTree.ShowDialog();
```

The `ShowDialog()` shows the form. I can't figure out how to access the folder path selected within this `BrowseTree` form in the current form.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a public Property in the `BrowseTree` class and set the folder path to it.

```
public class BrowseTree
{
    public string YourProperty {get; set;}

    //some code
}
```

Then:

```
BrowseTree bTree = new BrowseTree(connection);
bTree.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
DialogResult dialogResult = bTree.ShowDialog();

string value = bTree.YourProperty;
```

Comment: I close the `BrowseTree` form using `this.Close();` when the user clicks on a button. Will the property's value still exist?

Comment: Yes, if you set it in that form.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass data in many ways.  [Pass Data between forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms)

1. via constructors
2. via events
3. via public properties

   ```
   public string _textBox1
   {
       get{return textBox1.Text;}
   }
   ```

in form2 you can access like this

```
Form2 obj=new Form2();
string yourvalue=obj._textbox1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what is `BrowseTree` class, you can use [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) for this purpose. But if you have to use `BrowseTree` then define a property there for file path like:

```
public string FilePath {get;set;}
```

Set that property against the object

```
bTree.FilePath = "Your file path";
```

Later you can use that in your calling form.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog) how it's done in classic `OpenFileDialog`. It has a property with selected file name and you can access it from another form.

Comment: I am aware of `OpenFileDialog`. But I can't use it since it is a custom browse section on a server.

Comment: @SoulSlayer I'm not suggesting that you should use it. I'm just giving you a reference to base on. What I mean is that it's already done it this dialog, so you can use the same solution, because it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a public property in parent form like:

```
public string path{get;set;}
```

Then in child form close button:

parentobject.path="SelectedFolderPath";

hope this helps: